# How to create user collection in firestore after sign in with google?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am trying to create a user collection in firebase firestore after when user sign in with google.
i use these lines of code

```js
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    const provider = new fb.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    fb.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
    try {
      await fb.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
      fb.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        console.log("user sign in", result)
        DB.collection("users").add({
          username: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
          name : result.user.displayName,
          photo: result.user.photoURL,
          email: result.user.email,
          uid: result.user.uid,
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error", error.message)
    });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

but when i click on sign in button, user get sign in but after the signin this code could run

```js
.then(function(result) {
        console.log("user sign in", result)
        DB.collection("users").add({
          username: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
          name : result.user.displayName,
          photo: result.user.photoURL,
          email: result.user.email,
          uid: result.user.uid,
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error", error.message)
    })
```

but that code , did not called after user sign in.
neither console.log("user sign in",result) msg show in console section

Comment: You're not checking the result of the call to add().  It could be failing and you'd never know why.  Check for errors and see what happens.

Comment: It don't gives any kind of error. Not in console , not in terminal , not in web screen. It only return home page after signin.

Comment: Did you follow this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)?

Comment: i have tried that too . but it's not working

Comment: Can you add a catch block after then to show the error; so have tow catch. Just try

Comment: i add a catch block after then to show the error. but it do not gives any error. const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new fb.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      fb.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
      fb.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
          console.log("sign in rresult", result.user)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("error", error.message)
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

Comment: Can you try [this](https://bigcodenerd.org/create-user-profile-firestore-authentication/) once?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help , but i got another solution for this problem. and that's working very good. @RoopaM

Comment: @vipinbansal can you post your solution? it will be helpful for others who are facing the same issue

Comment: @RoopaM, i have posted my solution, please vote it thus it will reach to others who are facing this problem

Answer (score 1):

so this is the previous code , i had used

```js
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    const provider = new fb.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    fb.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
    try {
      await fb.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
      fb.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        console.log("user sign in", result)
        DB.collection("users").add({
          username: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
          name : result.user.displayName,
          photo: result.user.photoURL,
          email: result.user.email,
          uid: result.user.uid,
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error", error.message)
    });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

But the problem was that the second code(getRedirectResult()) was executed while the first code (signInWithRedirect(provider) was running. so its
obvious that the second code will give null value in result. because first code is not done.

To solve that problem , i separate these codes in diff files.
so in 'signin.js' file i write this code.

```js
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new fb.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      fb.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider) 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

and the rest of the code is written in the "App.js" file.

```js
fb.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    DB.collection("users").add({
      username: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
      name : result.user.displayName,
      photo: result.user.photoURL,
      email: result.user.email,
      uid: result.user.uid,
  });
});
```

And doing that solves the problem.

i recorded a youtube video also for this solution . you can watch here https://youtu.be/EKHk8tpd7dI